# Calling Java application from bat file and continue after its done?

Tags: java, batch-file

I am calling at batfile `App.bat` that calls a Java application:

```
echo %DATE%_%TIME% START >> log.log
App.bat import
echo %DATE%_%TIME% END >> log.log
```

Content in the `App.bat`

```
%JAVACMD% %JAVA_OPTS% %EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS% %APP_OPTS% -classpath %TS_CLASSPATH% org.App %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

where `org.App` is located in the App.jar file.

But after the `App.bat` bat file is done, the last line in the *wrapper* bat file is never executed:

```
echo %DATE%_%TIME% END >> log.log
```

How do I execute the last line after the call to the Java application have returned?

Comment: what is MyJavaApp ? is a class file or jar file ?

Comment: I am not batch expert but shouldn't your call `MyJavaApp import
` be `java MyJavaApp` or `java MyJavaApp import` (assuming that `import` is argument for `MyJavaApp`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works well for me, except that I have changed the Java class execution part.

**Callme.java**

```
public class Callme {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Called JavaApp");
    }
}
```

**CallMe.bat**

```
echo %DATE%_%TIME% START >> log.log
java Callme
echo %DATE%_%TIME% END >> log.log
```

**log.log** after execution of bat file

```
07/07/2015_13:39:10,79 START
07/07/2015_13:39:11,31 END
```

---

OK, now that you have changed your question, can you try the below and check if you are getting end date?

```
echo %DATE%_%TIME% START >> log.log
call App.bat import
echo %DATE%_%TIME% END >> log.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you don't have any problem with the Java program by calling the program as

```
MyJavaApp import
```

, below script has to work..

```
echo %DATE%_%TIME% >> "d:\New folder\log.log"
MyJavaApp import
echo %DATE%_%TIME% >> "d:\New folder\log.log"
```

Double check whether your Java program has completed. You can also double check whether the Java program is completed by passing a return code using

```
System.exit(anyInteger);
```

and get the code in batch and check for appropriate program status.

Answer (score -1):

Since I am a `batch` programmer I will tell you this (pretty sure it will work 100%.).

Remove the last line from the `batch` file, and in the `java` file make a code to start a file named "ENDLOG.bat".

Then make a file named "ENDLOG.bat"/A `batch` file named "ENDLOG".

Now remember the last line you removed from that batch file? Place in that `batch` file.

Comment: He writes it again, but without compiling.